# Can't decode values of thermometer, because 2 bytes become 1

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, hex, decode

I want to acquire data from a thermometer, which should give me the data in hex, but isn't always hex (somehow). ascii doesn't work, because the values are greater than 128. This is the sheet of the thermometer: https://asset.conrad.com/media10/add/160267/c1/-/en/000100518DS01/datenblatt-100518-voltcraft-k204-temperatur-messgeraet-200-1370-c-fuehler-typ-k-datenlogger-funktion.pdf

I want to decode the bytes, but because it isn't really hex and switches to something "weird" in between, I am not sure what to use

My code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM1',
                baudrate=9600,
                parity='N',
                bytesize=8,
                stopbits=1,
                rtscts=True,
                dsrdtr=True,
                timeout=1) # open serial port


ser.write(b'A') # send command 'A' to be able to receive data from VOLTCRAFT K204, see sheet
bytes=ser.readline() # read all 45 bytes
print(bytes)
selected_bytes=s[7:9]# slice to get the 8th and 9th value, see sheet
print(selected_bytes)
value= selected_bytes.decode('ascii') #doesn't work, because the value is out of range
print(value)
ser.close()
```

Output for 23.2°C, which is also shown on the thermometer:
b'\x02\x80\x80\x01\x02\x02\x02\x00\xe8\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x03'

b'\x00\xe8'

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Output for ~30.5°C, which is also shown on the thermometer:
b'\x02\x80\x80\x01\x02\x02\x02\x012\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x03'

b'\x012'

"unknown character"2

=> Not only did those 2 bytes become 1, but what exactly is b'\x012' and what can I use to decode both types of bytes?

If I only take one byte (because the other is 0) and let 'utf-8' decode it, I get values that are expected until I increase the temperature again and those 2 bytes become 1 again. Basically as soon as the thermometer uses the second byte I can't decode it

Comment: What if you try decoding the input data as `latin-1` to keep byte-to-byte mapping? Actually you don't really need to decode to string ; You just want to extract meaningful data from the data bytes..

Comment: You read binary data from the com port and then print it. Of course you get *something "weird"* when you print binary data, it's not meant for printing and doesn't make sense to decode it to ASCII.

Comment: @Jib you mean:
bytes=ser.readline().decode('latin-1') 
?

Comment: @jps with weird I meant that the 2 bytes become 1 which sometimes looks like '\x01*' which is not hex, but should be, and so IMO weird

Comment: When a byte has the value 1 (hex 01), Python prints it as \x01, because there is no printable character for 01. When the byte value happens to have the value of something printable, it prints the character. And there is nothing like "2 bytes become one". The hex value of a byte has always 2 digits (00 to FF), each digit represents 4 bits. But again, you handle binary data here, there is no ASCII, Latin-1 or anything else in it, and nothing to print.

Comment: As a side note, using `.readline()` for binary data runs the risk of stopping early if one of the binary bytes happens to correspond to a new-line character.  Using `.read()` or `.read(45)` instead would be safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving raw binary data.  `b'\x00\xe8'` is merely the text representation of that binary value.

The binary value in bytes can be converted to an integer using the `int.from_bytes` method:

```
raw  = b'\x00\xe8'
temp = int.from_bytes(raw,'big') / 10  # 23.9
```

Since those are temperatures, unless they are in Kelvin, I would expect that they can be negatives so you may want to use the signed option:

```
raw  = b'\xff\xef'
temp = int.from_bytes(raw,'big', signed=True) / 10  # -27.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is exactly what I've been looking for, something to turn bytes into integers

Answer (score 0):

Your sensor returns a raw data byte stream. You cannot just decode that stream and expect it to be printed HEX as ASCII.

If you want to print them as HEX you can go with:

```
stream = b'\x02\x80\x80\x01\x02\x02\x02\x00\xe8\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x03'
for d in stream.decode('latin-1'):
    print(hex(ord(d)))
```

However, in order to extract meaningful information, you have to keep the right data bytes and decode them as stated in the datasheet.

In your example, you get for channel #1 `0x00E8` which is `232` in base 10. Divide `232` by 10 and you get a measurement of `23.2`.

```
channel1 = stream[7:9]
for d in channel1.decode('latin-1'):
    print(hex(ord(d)))

rawvalue = (channel1[0] << 8) + channel1[1]
print(hex(rawvalue))
print(rawvalue / 10.0)
```